# Activity fragment communication using new android architecture (MVVM)

Tags: android, mvvm

The goal is to get info from a `Fragment`, so that the hosting `Activity` can display it. Let's take a simple example and assume that when a `Fragment` changes we want to display `Fragment`'s title from our `Activity`'s Action Bar.

Here's my old way of doing it:

`Activity`

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener( this );
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged( )
{
    BaseFragment fragment = mNavigationManager.getCurrentFragment( );

    if( fragment != null && fragment instanceof ActionBarProvider )
        mActionBarTitle.setText( ( ( ActionBarProvider ) fragment ).getTitle( ) );
}
```

ActionBarProvider

```java
public interface ActionBarProvider
{
    String getTitle( );
}
```

Fragment

```java
// implements ActionBarProvider

@Override
protected String getTitle( )
{
    return "Hello world";
}
```

---

Here's what I think of doing with MVVM:

Activity

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of( this, mViewModelFactory ).get( MainViewModel.class );
    mViewModel.getTitle( ).observe( this, s -> mActionBarTitle.setText( s ) );
}
```

MainViewModel

```java
private MutableLiveData< String > mTitle = new MutableLiveData<>( );

public MutableLiveData< String > getTitle( )
{
    return mTitle;
}

public void setTitle( String title )
{
    mTitle.postValue( title );
}
```

Fragment

```java
@Override
public void onActivityCreated( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onActivityCreated( savedInstanceState );

    MainViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders
            .of( getActivity( ), mViewModelFactory )
            .get( MainViewModel.class );

    viewModel.setTitle( "hello world" );
}
```

---

The MVVM looks cleaner but it assumes that `Fragment` knows its main `Activity` ViewModel:

```java
MainViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders
            .of( getActivity( ), mViewModelFactory )
            .get( MainViewModel.class );
```

So if you move `Fragment` to another `Activity` this won't work.
Should I keep the old way? Or have you guys any other way to do this kind of communication using MVVM?

Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a golden rule using ViewModels. Everything beginning with Android packages in your import is wrong except *.arch packages.

You don't set the title in your actvity, since it's bound to the fragment.

Use `getActivity().setTitle()` in your `onStart`/`onResume` method in your fragment.

ViewModels are bound to the fragment OR to the host activity. Changing the activity will also call `onCleared()` in your ViewModel. You can't share data between several activties using your ViewModel.

Creating an interface to share data is not MVVM. It's MVP and should be avoided using MVVM and [Google's AAC](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/).

Since several activities may be a host for your fragments you should never access the activity directly. Better use `if (getActivity() != null) { getActivity().setTitle(...) }` in your fragment.

By the way, if you don't modify the getter/setter you should also use `public final LiveData` and avoid using getters and setters. Your `LiveData` instance won't change, but the data does. Means `final` is just fine.

```
public final LiveData<String> mTitle = new MutableLiveData<String>();
```

You should also consider using `setValue()` to set the data if you dont want to append but replace the data.

*So if you move fragment to another activity this won't work. Should I keep the old way? Or have you guys any other way to do this kind of communication using MVVM?*

ViewModels can ONLY be shared between fragments and the hosting activity, but it can't shared using several activities.

Comment: Thx for the answer (and advices) this is clearing my mind. So assuming we have a MainActivity bottom navigation (instead of a actionbar title) and for one fragment you wanna hide it, you will call `getActivity().setBottomNavigationVisibility( true/false);`  for each fragments?

Comment: Yes, this is one working solution. Using an interface to communicate between fragment and activity is another. Always double-check if the activity is still avilable using getActivity != null.

Comment: By the way, if you use MVVM you rather want to use Databindng. Then you can use bindingadapters for those stuff which is highly recommended.

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure how to use Databinding to inject actionbar title depending on fragment, have you any example?